# how to use mysqldump command in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to backup my database. So I've used this command

`$command = "mysqldump --user=root asset_management > D:\assetmanagement\public\backup\backup.sql";
system($command);`

But this will produce an empty sql file.. can anyone help?

Comment: so there's no password on your mysql server for the user root?

Comment: You could add ` 2> errors.log` to the command and see if there were any errors

Comment: is mysqldump in the path of whatever shell is being used? did you try running this command yourself from your own shell, and a shell running under your webserver's UID?

Comment: @pankar: Your comment isn't really helpful. Posting a link to a Google search is generally frowned upon, unless the question is something like "Can't think of good search terms to find an answer to my question." The OP has shown what he has tried, and clearly has an idea of how to use the `mysqldump` command. If you see something specific that he's doing wrong, point it out.

Comment: this command worked when i trying this cmd in cmd. but when i want used it inside of the php code. i tried it lots of diffent ways.
exec("mysql --u root asset_management > D:\assetmanagement\public\backup\backup1.sql");

Comment: I'm not really sure why it's producing an empty file, but could it have something to do with your backslashes? In a double-quoted PHP string, a single backslash is an escape character, so you're escaping `a`, `p`, `b`, and another `b`. Try changing all of your backslashes to double-backslashes (to escape the backslash character).

Comment: @Travesty3 IMHO the OP hasn't exhausted all the possible ways to perform a successful `mysqldump` and my comment was just a shortcut to this one. Besides it was just a comment not an answer.

Comment: MarcB has probably called it, and  Jack's suggestion has merit. A lot of the time this is simply permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your mysqldump is in the C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.33/bin/ folder

```
$mysqlPath="C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.33/bin/";
//There should be password for root user. Blank password will not work.

$command = $mysqlPath . "mysqldump.exe asset_management > D:\assetmanagement\public\backup\backup.sql --user=root --password=yourpassword ";
```

Answer (score 1):

**`$command = "mysqldump --user=root -pass=yourpassword asset_management > D:\assetmanagement\public\backup\backup.sql"; system($command);`**